# GUI in vehicle infotainment system?

Tags: user-interface

Which GUIs would be used in vehicles for radios, gps devices, infotainment systems?

Comment: What do you mean by "GUI"? Are you referring to what programming framework / widget set they use? That's a bit like asking "what are wedding dresses, fur coats, speedos made out of?"

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use proprietary ones.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2ME/TLA.html) is an article about a system based on Java, which is already a few years old. It was/is used in high-end systems of BMW and VW.

Answer (score 0):

In my company, as far as I know, we have used four types of GUI framework (flash/Qt/HTML5/Internal proprietary HMI framework) for projects.

HTML5 is adopted for Linux based projects which are GENIVI compliance. http://investor.harman.com/releasedetail.cfm?releaseid=817096

Comment: what GUI is used in the reference implementation of GDP?